# Hazelcast TargetNotMemberException: Not Member! target

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have seen a lot of posts about a `com.hazelcast.spi.exception.TargetNotMemberException: Not Member! target:`

But what to do in this cases? Question : Is possible to catch the exception and do "hazelCastInstance.shutdown()`"

Also its possible to see in the "wrong node" continously :  "*Remaining migration tasks in queue => 1"*

Hazelcast 3.7  Cluster with two nodes.

Complete StackTrace:

```
com.hazelcast.spi.exception.TargetNotMemberException: Not Member! target: [machine]:5704, partitionId: 0, operation: com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.QueryPartitionOperation, service: hz:impl:mapService
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.initInvocationTarget(Invocation.java:324)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvoke(Invocation.java:256)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.access$300(Invocation.java:94)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation$InvocationRetryTask.run(Invocation.java:530)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:682)
        at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)
        at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:92)
        at ------ submitted from ------.(Unknown Source)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolve(InvocationFuture.java:111)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolveAndThrow(InvocationFuture.java:74)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:158)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.MapQueryEngineImpl.addResultsOfPredicate(MapQueryEngineImpl.java:605)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.MapQueryEngineImpl.invokeQueryAllPartitions(MapQueryEngineImpl.java:506)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.entrySet(MapProxyImpl.java:633)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.entrySet(MapProxyImpl.java:622)
        at myClass.getAll(MyClass.java:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

TargetNotMemberException extends RetryableHazelcastException which further extends HazelcastException , so you can catch HazelcastException and then shutdown the instance or you can catch directly  TargetNotMemberException and shutdown Hazelcast instance. You can look into below class.

[TargetNotMemberException.java](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/spi/exception/TargetNotMemberException.java)

You can code like this...

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import com.hazelcast.config.Config;
import com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast;
import com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException;
import com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance;
import com.hazelcast.spi.exception.TargetNotMemberException;

public class HazelcastExceptionTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Config config = new Config("instanceOne");
        HazelcastInstance instanceOne = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);

        try {
            testTargetNotMemberException();
        }
        catch (HazelcastException e) {
            StringWriter trace = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter eTrace = new PrintWriter(trace, true);
            e.printStackTrace(eTrace);
            System.out.println("exception " + trace.toString());
            instanceOne.shutdown();

        }
    }

    public static void testTargetNotMemberException() {
        throw new TargetNotMemberException("TargetNotMemberException");
    }
}
```